# Create Android App Level Screen

Tags: android, android-image

I am creating an app that the user logs into via Firebase authentication and uses a Firebase realtime database to store user level data. The levels are just level 1, 2, 3, and so on.

The users will get a Star Rating of 1, 2, or 3 stars for each level depending on certain conditions. 
[image: Sample image screen]

This is a sample of what I want to create. I am wondering about how to best implement this.

Should I have individual blue squares with 1, 2, and 3 stars and a blue square with a padlock as 4 separate image resource files. Doing it that way, I would have to figure out which one to display and manually position it on the screen.

Should I have one image with 15 squares? Doing it that way, I would just have to control the visibility of the stars on each square and optionally superimpose a number or a padlock over each square.

Am I making this too difficult? I am asking for recommendations.

Thanks.

Comment: Down votes for asking for advice? I did do research. I googled and couldn't find anything, so I figured I would ask a question here. And look, someone gave me an answer.

Comment: You need 3 images with varied selected stars + 1 image for non-finished level + 1 image for the lock. All in all you need 5 images. If you are still confused feel free to chat any of us here.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have it figured out now. I will try the RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager sample as shown in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`.
Refer [this](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-gridlayoutmanager-with-recyclerview-in-material-design/)

Comment: Thank you for the reference. That does look useful. I will give it a try.